# Always ensuring text editor ends with X text

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently implementing a form that allows the user to input a lengthy message. For this application, the user's text must have some preset text added to the end.

An example would be:

`Hello, I'm a message. END`

How would I add the 'END' text in a text editor and enforce it to always remain at the end of the text? I want to show it there at all times and disallow the user from deleting or editing it. Do you know if this is possible?

My initial thoughts would be to on the TextChanged event, check if the characters are already on the end, and if they are not, delete them. But simple logic like that just seems bound to cause problems, and I was wondering if there is a known method of doing something like this, as unusual as it may seem.

Comment: what platform? winforms, web, wpf, silverlight, winrt, etc.?

Comment: Why do you want to see the text in the TextBox? You could add it after the user entered the text.

Comment: What if the user wants to enter "THIS IS THE END"? Is the _END_ the end or does it belong to the text, how do you want to recognize it?

Comment: It's not a design question, I'm asking if it is possible.

Comment: I just want to be able to enforce a textbox always having a selection of characters added to the end. It is for clarity to the user.

Comment: It's possible, but why not just add it to the result after the fact? Users might be confused if there is some text in the box that looks editable (and everything else is editable) but it won't let them change it.

Comment: @280Z28 My question was how to implement it, not if it is a good idea or not - I'll be the judge of that after I have implemented it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a handler for the [`KeyPress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx) event, and if the key represents an edit that you don't want applied set the value of [`KeyPressEventArgs.Handled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.handled.aspx) to true before returning.

Answer (score 0):

If you need predefined text at the end of text entered by user then add that text at the end of message in code behind. Use text which are very rare to be entered by the user. Like `##END##`. So you knows `##END##` is the end of the message. When showing that message back to editor substring message till the index of `##END##` in your code and display only actual message to the user.